# How to call the next swift combine publisher in turn if the previous one reported an error?

Tags: combine

There are three publishers. First you need to try the first, if an error occurs, then use the second, if again an error, then use the third, if there is a failure, then return the last error. Important: you cannot call in parallel, it is necessary to follow the sequence. I have an assumption that the scan method should be used, but I do not understand how exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Catch` is what allows you to return a publisher when an upstream error occurs. Generally speaking, the set-up would look like so:

```
publisher1
   .catch { err1 in
      publisher2
   }
   .catch { err2 in
      publisher3
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very match!

Comment: In this case, it would be sufficient to use `.catch { _ in publisher2 }` because the closure cannot throw an error.

Comment: @robmayoff, are you sure? I thought that `.catch` requires that the returned publisher having a `Never` failure

Comment: No, the `catch` operator allows any `Failure` type. If a Combine operator has `try` in the name, it means the operator takes a throwing closure and returns a `Publisher` with a `Failure` type of `Error`.

Comment: Ah, you're right... will change the answer